# Using TFRecords with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have transformed an image database into two TFRecords, one for training and the other for validation. I want to train a simple model with keras using these two files for data input but I obtain an error I can't understand related to the shape of the data.

Here is the code (all-capital variables are defined elsewhere):

```
def _parse_function(proto):
    f = {
        "x": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([IMG_SIZE[0] * IMG_SIZE[1]], tf.float32, default_value=0., allow_missing=True),
        "label": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([1], tf.int64, default_value=0, allow_missing=True)
    }
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(proto, f)

    x = tf.reshape(parsed_features['x'] / 255, (IMG_SIZE[0], IMG_SIZE[1], 1))
    y = tf.cast(parsed_features['label'], tf.float32)
    return x, y

def load_dataset(input_path, batch_size, shuffle_buffer):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(input_path)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer).repeat()  # shuffle and repeat
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=16)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)  # batch and prefetch

    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

train_iterator = load_dataset(TRAIN_TFRECORDS, BATCH_SIZE, SHUFFLE_BUFFER)
val_iterator = load_dataset(VALIDATION_TFRECORDS, BATCH_SIZE, SHUFFLE_BUFFER)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(IMG_SIZE[0], IMG_SIZE[1], 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(
    train_iterator,
    epochs=N_EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=N_TRAIN // BATCH_SIZE,
    validation_data=val_iterator,
    validation_steps=N_VALIDATION // BATCH_SIZE

)
```

And here is the error I obtain:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: data[0].shape = [3] does not start with indices[0].shape = [2]
     [[Node: training/TFOptimizer/gradients/loss/dense_loss/Mean_grad/DynamicStitch = DynamicStitch[N=2, T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@training/TFOptimizer/gradients/loss/dense_loss/Mean_grad/floordiv"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](training/TFOptimizer/gradients/loss/dense_loss/Mean_grad/range, training/TFOptimizer/gradients/loss/dense_loss/Mean_3_grad/Maximum, training/TFOptimizer/gradients/loss/dense_loss/Mean_grad/Shape/_35, training/TFOptimizer/gradients/loss/dense_loss/Mean_3_grad/Maximum/_41)]]
```

(I know that the model defined here is not a good model for image analysis, I just took the simplest possible architecture that reproduces the error)

Comment: Can you try `"label": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([]` instead of `[1]`?

Comment: That fixed it! Can you explain me why? (and if you transform it into an answer I will be glad to accept it and upvote it)

Comment: Done. Unfortunately, I cannot give much of an explanation for it. But I recognized your mistake from my own painful experience.

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi AFAIK [] means scalar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
"label": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([1]...
```

into:

```
"label": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([]...
```

This is unfortunately not explained in the documentation on the website, but [some explanation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/ops/parsing_ops.py#L171) can be found in the docstring of `FixedLenSequenceFeature` on github. Basically, if your data consists of a single dimension (+ a batch dimension), you don't need to specify it.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, there is still a problem left: this works only if I remove the validation part from the `model.fit()` function. Otherwise, I get this error: `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not Dimension`. Does it ring a bell to you?

Comment: Hmm no, haven't encountered that one yet. Strange, I don't see why it should give an error for the validation iterator but not for the training iterator. Did you try directly passing the datasets? (as in the other answer)

Comment: I updated tensorflow to version 1.12 from 1.8 and the issue disappeared. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ah yes. A lot of the tf.keras api integrations with tf.data have come in the most recent versions of TensorFlow.

Answer (score 4):

You have forget to this line from [the example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#parsing_tfexample_protocol_buffer_messages):

```
parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(proto, f)
```

Add it to `_parse_function`.

Also, you can return just the `dataset` object. Keras supports iterators as well as instances of the `tf.data.Dataset`. Also, it looks a bit weird to shuffle and repeat first, and then to parse tfexamples. Here is an example code that works for me:

```
def dataset(filenames, batch_size, img_height, img_width, is_training=False):
    decoder = TfExampleDecoder()

    def preprocess(image, boxes, classes):
            image = preprocess_image(image, resize_height=img_height, resize_width=img_width)
        return image, groundtruth

    ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    ds = ds.map(decoder.decode, num_parallel_calls=8)
    if is_training:
        ds = ds.shuffle(1000 + 3 * batch_size)
    ds = ds.apply(tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(map_func=preprocess, batch_size=batch_size, num_parallel_calls=8))
    ds = ds.repeat()
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)
    return ds


train_dataset = dataset(args.train_data, args.batch_size,
                        args.img_height, args.img_width,
                        is_training=True)


model.fit(train_dataset,
          steps_per_epoch=args.steps_per_epoch,
          epochs=args.max_epochs,
          callbacks=callbacks,
          initial_epoch=0)
```

It seems like an issue with your data or preprocessing pipeline, rather than with Keras. Try to inspect what you are getting out of the dataset with a debugging code like:

```
ds = dataset(args.data, args.img_height, args.img_width, is_training=True)

image_t, classes_t = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        image, classes = sess.run([image_t, classes_t])
        # Do something with the data: display, log etc.
```

Comment: Hi Dmytro, thanks for pointing out the missing line, I corrected it. The parse is done after shuffle and repeat because shuffling the raw data is supposedly faster than shuffling the parsed one, I don't think it matters much though. Thank you also for pointing out I can use raw datasets instead of iterators. However, the solution is the error in the parse function that sdcbr pointed out.

Comment: Actually, I tried to use raw datasets instead of iterators and it doesn't work. It says: `ValueError: You passed a 'Dataset' instance to your model (<PrefetchDataset shapes: ((?, 96, 96, 1), (?, ?)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>), which is not supported. Instead, pass an 'Iterator', which you can obtain e.g. via 'dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()' (the exact method to use will depend on your specific dataset)`.

Comment: Hmm, weird. It must work: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model#fit   Maybe, you use an older version of tensorflow.

Comment: You were right. I was stuck with Tensorflow 1.8. Updating it solved the issue.

Comment: @DmytroPrylipko I tried your code, facing one issue.
NameError: name 'TfExampleDecoder' is not defined

Comment: @Balaji `TfExampleDecoder` must be a user custom class that decodes TFRecords. Something like https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py#L136